# Vue is not loaded properly in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack

I am adding vuejs into my rails app with webpack version 5.44.0. I just embedded hello vuejs text into home index page, but I'm getting below error, how can I fix it?

```
main.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module../node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js?!./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=template&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true (main.js:58)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=template&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true (app.vue?b2b1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app/javascript/app.vue (app.vue?080e:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/hello_vue.js (hello_vue.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
vue.runtime.esm.js:8452 Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools
vue.runtime.esm.js:8457 You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

​
```

`hello_vue.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '../app.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount()

})
```

And attach it to `#app` element in home/index page:

```
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: are you using vue cli?

Comment: No I dont, just intending to add Vuejs page into my Rails application. I tried with simple element but getting error